# Ubuntu w/ KDE - Using Tahoma or Segoe UI in Firefox makes text disappear

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, kde

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and hated the new Gnome, so I installed KDE 4.8.

The default Firefox fonts are disgusting, so I tried changing them to the Windows ones. I copied the Tahoma and Segoe UI fonts from my Windows install and put them in ~/.fonts. I ran `sudo fc-cache -f -v`.

When I change the "General" font in `System > Application Appearance > Fonts` to "Tahoma" or "Segoe UI", all of the text for tabs and menus in Firefox disappears completely.

Why is this happening? Why can't I use those fonts with Firefox?

Comment: Are the typeface(s) available (and work) in other applications?